# S parameters measurement inside VNA

Tags: network, vna

How does a Vector Network Analyzer (VNA) measure S parameters actually?

Namely we have equations:

\$b_1=S_{11}a_1+S_{12}a_2\$

\$b_2=S_{12}a_1+S_{22}a_2 \$

In theory, if i wanted to calculate scattering parameters I would have to be able to make perfect matching on the source (\$a_1=0\$) and on the load side (\$a_2=0\$).

Unfortunately I do not understand how is this done inside the VNA. If I want to measure scattering parameters of a random network with input and output impedance different than 50ohm, how is in this case achieved \$a_1=0\$ and \$a_2=0\$?

Comment: I think you would need to take into consideration the measurement (reflection/transmission) uncertainty after calibration. A VNA will assume ideal conditions during the calibration, but due to the fact that your DUT cannot achieve ideal matching, the measured s-Parameters will only be sufficiently certain inside a certain boundary. For example: if you try to measure a GOhm impedance, the VNA will just show you an open circuit.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a good basic explanation about [how a VNA works](https://www.mwrf.com/test-measurement/brushing-network-analyzer-fundamentals).

An excerpt follows:

[image: Simplified block diagram of a VNA with two test ports]

> To measure S11 or S21, the switch would route the signal toward Port
>   1. The signal first enters a directional device, shown as Directional Device R1 in Figure. This directional device could be a directional
>   coupler or bridge. A power divider could also be used here. The
>   purpose of this device is to direct a portion of the input signal to a
>   reference receiver, shown as Reference Receiver 1. Once the signal
>   enters this reference receiver, it’s downconverted and ultimately
>   processed.
>
> The signal that passes through Directional Device R1 then passes
>   through another directional device, shown as Directional Device M1 in
>   Figure, before arriving at the DUT. When the signal does arrive at the
>   DUT, a portion is reflected back to Port 1 of the VNA and reenters
>   Directional Device M1. This device now directs a portion of the
>   reflected signal to a measurement receiver, shown as Measurement
>   Receiver 1. Next, this signal is downconverted and processed. The VNA
>   can then compare the data obtained from Measurement Receiver 1 with
>   the data obtained from Reference Receiver 1. This process summarizes
>   how S11 is measured.
>
> The signal applied to the DUT also results in a transmitted signal,
>   which exits the DUT and enters Port 2 of the VNA. This transmitted
>   signal enters another directional device, shown as Directional Device
>   M2 in Figure. This device directs a portion of the signal to another
>   measurement receiver, shown as Measurement Receiver 2. This signal is
>   subsequently downconverted and processed. Now, the VNA can compare the
>   data obtained from Measurement Receiver 2 with the data obtained from
>   Reference Receiver 1. This process summarizes how S21 is measured.
>
> To measure S22 or S12, the switch would route the signal to Port 2.
>   The same process occurs in the opposite direction: The signal first
>   enters Directional Device R2 in Figure, which directs a portion of the
>   signal to Reference Receiver 2. After entering this reference
>   receiver, the signal is downconverted and processed.
>
> The signal that passes through Directional Device R2 then passes
>   through Directional Device M2 on its way toward the DUT. After
>   arriving at the DUT, a portion of the signal is reflected back to Port
>   2 of the VNA and reenters Directional Device M2. Now, a portion of
>   this reflected signal is directed to Measurement Receiver 2.
>   Afterward, this signal is downconverted and processed. The data
>   obtained from Measurement Receiver 2 can then be compared with the
>   data obtained from Reference Receiver 2, thus summarizing the S22
>   measurement process.
>
> The signal that’s transmitted through the DUT enters Port 1 of the
>   VNA. This transmitted signal enters Directional Device M1 in Figure,
>   which directs a portion of the signal to Measurement Receiver 1. This
>   signal is likewise downconverted and processed. The data obtained from
>   Measurement Receiver 1 can now be compared with the data obtained from
>   Reference Receiver 2, thus summarizing the S12 measurement process.

If you want to obtain S-parameters of a network with input/output impedance other than 50-ohm, these must be recalculated afterwards from the already measured, 50-ohm referenced S-parameters.

Answer (score 1):

The HP8505 used directional couplers inside a special module located below the display/sweep/storage/compute unit.

Comment: For what purpose did thy use them?